# Use animate to make an object go through fixed xs and ys

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm generating in a function x and y and the generation is looped up to a moment. I wonder to use .animate() in order to move my object from one point, defined by the x and y pairs, to another. So far I've something like this:

```
while(condition){
  x=formula...;
  y=formula...;
}
```

I also have an image #ball{top: , left: } which I'd like to move from one (x;y) to its next one, then till the third, fourth and so on to the end.
I know I can simply do this with .css() but if it can be done by .animate I'll definitely prefer it. I know the question is sort of dumb one but I really lack knowledge how to do it with this particular function, so... I'm looking forward to your answers. :)

Comment: Consider all the points of your route as distinguished pairs of x and y. So you should be able to create an array of those and iterate over it.

Comment: so, it'll be sth like for(var i; i<=n;i++){
                               for(var j;j<=n;i++){
                                $("#ball").animate({top:arr[j], left:arr[i]}, 450);
}}
?

Comment: Sort of! I don't know if `animate` makes sense here in particular, but give it a try! I suggest you try to produce some working code and come back if you get issues.

Comment: May you just clarify one more problem for me? I face some difficulties about how to use .push for a two dimentional array. Give me a sample, please :) because I need to store the pairs in it and then send it to another function which cares about the movement... :)

Comment: What is your 2D structure about?